# Filter "From Review" Comments in Profile

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page, automatic-comments

From time to time I like to revisit my old comments, in case someone has replied without tagging me (this happens occasionally).

In my profile under *all actions* --> *comments*, the list includes many comments that are generated "From Review". I'd like a way to filter these out, so that I can see a list of just the comments I've composed, and not those that are auto-generated.

Comment: What's the difference between comments composed and comments generated? Am I missing something?

Comment: If there are many such comments, this means you were recommending deletion of many posts that were not deleted. Perhaps this is the thing to change.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, the review process generates automatic comments on behalf of reviewers. These comments are composed by SO, not by the reviewers themselves. Basically, I didn't write the comments, so I'd like to filter them out of the list of comments that I did write.

Comment: If you are doing it right, such comments should be deleted before 24 hours are up.

Comment: @Marshmallow, I attribute that phenomenon to robo-reviewers approving posts that should be deleted.

Comment: It would be nice just to have a comment search or include comments in the SO search with a `is:comment`